# Defaultvalue for IterationPath in WorkitemType

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2017 SP1

If I'm creating a new Bug in the queries tab, the Iteration Path is always set to the current iteration we're working on.

Is it possible to set the default value of the iteration path with the REST API of the TFS server?

There's unfortunatelly no example. It has to be in an area like this...

```
http://tfs:8080/tfs/<collection>/<project>/_apis/wit/fields/System.IterationPath
```

P.s.: I'm not able to edit the Project Template via the Power Tools. Is this normal for TFS 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the REST API, in TFS 2017 you can set the default iteration via web portal:

**Team Settings** (gear icon) >> **Work** >> Click the link "`click here`" behind the string "`To access the default team's iteration settings`".  >> **Iterations** >> **Default Iteration** >> **Change** >> Select the iteration >> **Set**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made my day (a second time).